# What is the criteria for showing a dereference of a possible null reference warning?

Tags: c#, .net, warnings, .net-6.0

I have a QueryExecutor file in my onion microservice architecture, and I get a dereference of a possibly null reference warning in code bellow:

```cs
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAll<T>() where T : BaseEntity
    => await _mongoDbContext.GetCollection<T>()
                            .Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();

public async Task UpdateAsync<T>(FilterDefinition<T> filterDefinition, UpdateDefinition<T> updateDefinition) where T : BaseEntity
    => await _mongoDbContext.GetCollection<T>()
                            .UpdateOneAsync(filterDefinition, updateDefinition);
```

Only the Update method gives the warning and I think I understand it - the mongoDbContext.GetCollection() could return a null value. But what I don't understand is why doesn't the GetAll method return it as well. The only difference I see is that Update return value is a void Task and Update has a read only collection.

Comment: Doesn't GetAll method return an empty collection instead of null?

Comment: GetAll returns all the documents from a collections, if that's what you meant. If what you meant was  _mongoDbContext.GetCollection<T>() in the GetAll method, it does return a Collection, specified by the type T, using the CollectionName attribute.